# React Formik with Ant InputNumber type error

Tags: reactjs, types, typeerror, antd, formik

I am implementing ant designs `InputNumber` with Formik Field. I am keep on getting the same error which is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`. The call stack of this error dives somewhere deep into formik.

My code is very simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import { InputNumber } from 'antd';

export const FormExample = () => (
  <Formik>
    {props => (
      <Form>
        <Field
          as={InputNumber}
          name="number"
        />
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
)
```

Have you got some idea what's going on here? When I put `InputNumber` normally without `<Field />` everything works ok, but I want to have proper integration with formik.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'wire-up' the `onChange` and `value` of InputNumber to Formik.

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-feather-nmm04

```
export default function App() {
  const handleChange = (name, setFieldValue) => value => {
    setFieldValue(name, value);
  };

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ number: 222 }}>
      {props => (
        <Field
          as={InputNumber}
          name="number"
          onChange={handleChange("number", props.setFieldValue)}
          value={props.values.number}
        />
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Formiks setFieldValue function to set the value of the input field to set it's value.

```
<Formik initialValues={{ number: 222 }}>
      {props => (
        <Field
          as={InputNumber}
          name="number"
          onChange={(value)=>{ props.setFieldValue("number", value)}}
          value={props.values.number}
        />
      )}
</Formik>
```